# selenium: find element not working (should be quick, so plz help)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, click, undetected-chromedriver

trying to click on "i accept" button but doesn't work

```
import time
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
import selenium
def login_Undetected():
    driver = uc.Chrome()
    driver.get('https://krunker.io/')
    time.sleep(4)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[id*=onetrust-accept-btn-handler]").click()
    time.sleep(2)
   
login_Undetected()
```

gives error:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[id*=onetrust-accept-btn-handler]").click()
```

File "C:\Users\hi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver_*init*_.py", line 433, in **getattribute**
return super().**getattribute**(item)
AttributeError: 'Chrome' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_css_selector'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `find_element` instead.

`find_element_by_css_selector` doesn't exist anymore.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[id*=onetrust-accept-btn-handler]')
```

Comment: thx very much, also i just want to ask, how would i press a button as soon as it is pressable on the site (it loads a bit after the site)

Comment: atm im just using sleep and also a lot of the information on this seems outdated